# Difference between a variable being "in scope" and being "visible"?

Tags: scope, visibility

(This is SIMILAR in concept to a homework problem, but the answers you give me cannot be used to answer the problem, only to help me understand the concept.)

Say I have this C++ program:

```
int main(){
   int i = 5;
   if(true){
      int i = 3;
      [REFERENCE POINT]
   }
}
```

Let's refer to the first version of "i" (the one that's equal to 5) as i(1) and the other version (the one that's equal to 3) as i(2).

I know there is some difference between a variable being in scope and being visible, so I'm trying to determine, at the reference point, which "i"s would be in scope, and which would be visible, and what is the difference?

EDIT: I've been reading that all variables in a scope are visible unless they are overridden.  So would it be correct to say that both i(1) and i(2) are in scope, but only i(2) is visible (at the reference point)?

Comment: Are we to assume C? C++?

Comment: C++, sorry I forgot to include that.